# Persian font in Netbeans cause speed reduction

Tags: macos, fonts, netbeans

I have speed problem in Netbeans 7.0 IDE when my current open document has any Persian font inside it. If it happens, the speed of software incredibly reduce. ( for example if I hit backspace, it takes about 10 seconds to respond ). The amazing part is when I open a fully english document in Netbeans there is no problem and everything works well.

I'm running Netbeans 7.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.2. This problem happens with every fonts( even with fully Persian fonts). But I really want to have Persian with Monospaced font. (Netbeans default font)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do all Java apps on your system have problems with Persian fonts, or just Netbeans?

Comment: @Spiff: just netbeans :(

Comment: Any help ? Nothing ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I'm not really a Java or Netbeans person. You should consider offering a bounty to see if you can attract the attention of someone who is. Or maybe see if a different Stack Exchange site might have a better audience for this question.

By the way, does Netbeans have problems with just Farsi, or with all RTL languages? A little quick Googling makes it sound like Netbeans just sucks for all RTL languages, but I didn't see anyone else complaining about 10 second delays hitting backspace.